# Getting error while trasferring a file through prepare for segue method use of undeclared type of destination viewcontroller in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "stopRecording" {
        let playsoundVC = segue.destination as! RecordsoundViewCAONTROLLER
        let recordAudioURL = sender as! URL
        playsoundVC.recordAudioURL = recordAudioURL
    }
}
```

I am transferring audio file from one viewcontroller to other but I am getting an error i.e : Use of undeclared type 'RecordsoundViewCAONTROLLER'

Comment: You have a typo.. RecordsoundViewCAONTROLLER <<

Comment: do you have any such controller? or please verify spelling , and even better correct it something like-: RecordSoundViewController.

Comment: Does XCode give you a hint at what the issue is? It can sometimes detect misspellings/casing/etc and suggest the fix.